# Problem with registry file in Windows XP 32-bit

Tags: windows

My windows prevented errors messages and the technician said it's because of the size of the file:

```
C:\Windows\System32\config\system
```

in my computer is 12MB.

I have Windows XP - 32-bit witch doesn't support this file to be more than 12MB.

Is there any convenient way to deal with it besides to perform regclean every time?

Comment: Adding some more information about the exact errors you are experiencing would help getting a good answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Well according to [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/292726) the limit has been removed in XP:

> In Microsoft Windows Server 2003 and in Microsoft Windows XP, the Registry Size Limit (RSL) functionality has been removed. Therefore, there are no longer any limits on the total amount of space that may be consumed by registry data (hives) in paged pool memory, and in disk space.

So it would appear that this can't be the problem.

[This related article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/124594):

> describes Registry Size Limit (RSL) and tells how to configure it.

So it could be that a limit has been applied. Follow the instructions and see if that's the case. If so increase the value.